# Como colocar o nome da variável dependente em um looping de uma regressão e guardar os resultados no R

Tags: r, regressão

Olá, fiz o seguinte código para gerar uma regressão em loop:

```
t <- c( "mpg", "vs")
teste <- c()

res_list <- lapply(t, \(coluna) {
  dataset$y <- dataset[, .SD, .SDcols = coluna]
  #calculando a regressão
  lm(y ~ cyl + hp + wt, dataset)
  
})

res_list |>
  purrr::map(summary) |>
  purrr::map(broom::tidy) |>
  dplyr::bind_rows()
```

Ele me gerar o seguinte resultado no console do R:

```
A tibble: 8 × 5
  term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 (Intercept) 38.8       1.79       21.7   4.80e-19
2 cyl         -0.942     0.551      -1.71  9.85e- 2
3 hp          -0.0180    0.0119     -1.52  1.40e- 1
4 wt          -3.17      0.741      -4.28  1.99e- 4
5 (Intercept)  1.73      0.213       8.14  7.37e- 9
6 cyl         -0.237     0.0656     -3.61  1.19e- 3
7 hp          -0.00119   0.00141    -0.841 4.08e- 1
8 wt           0.107     0.0882      1.22  2.34e- 1
> View(res_list)
```

Eu consigo incluir desses resultados o nome da variável nesse resultado? O que deixaria a saída da seguinte forma:

```
A tibble: 8 × 6
  term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value  variavel
  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>   
1 (Intercept) 38.8       1.79       21.7   4.80e-19   mpg
2 cyl         -0.942     0.551      -1.71  9.85e- 2   mpg
3 hp          -0.0180    0.0119     -1.52  1.40e- 1   mpg
4 wt          -3.17      0.741      -4.28  1.99e- 4   mpg
5 (Intercept)  1.73      0.213       8.14  7.37e- 9   vs
6 cyl         -0.237     0.0656     -3.61  1.19e- 3   vs
7 hp          -0.00119   0.00141    -0.841 4.08e- 1   vs
8 wt           0.107     0.0882      1.22  2.34e- 1   vs
> View(res_list)
```

E eu consigo transformar essa saída em uma tabela ou data.frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nomeie a lista com resultados e use a opção `.id` da `dplyr::bind_rows()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(broom)

cols <- c("mpg", "vs")

res_list <- lapply(cols, \(y) lm(formula(paste(y, "~ cyl + hp + wt")), mtcars))

res_list |>
  setNames(cols) |>
  map(summary) |>
  map(tidy) |>
  bind_rows(.id = "variavel")
#> # A tibble: 8 × 6
#>   variavel term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>    <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 mpg      (Intercept) 38.8       1.79       21.7   4.80e-19
#> 2 mpg      cyl         -0.942     0.551      -1.71  9.85e- 2
#> 3 mpg      hp          -0.0180    0.0119     -1.52  1.40e- 1
#> 4 mpg      wt          -3.17      0.741      -4.28  1.99e- 4
#> 5 vs       (Intercept)  1.73      0.213       8.14  7.37e- 9
#> 6 vs       cyl         -0.237     0.0656     -3.61  1.19e- 3
#> 7 vs       hp          -0.00119   0.00141    -0.841 4.08e- 1
#> 8 vs       wt           0.107     0.0882      1.22  2.34e- 1
```

OBS1: Não precisa criar uma nova coluna chamada *y* no seu *data.frame*.

OBS2: é uma prática ruim usar nomes de funções comuns (p.e. t) para seus objetos.